# JFace TableViewer Listener to deselect previously selected row

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer

Does anybody knows any how to deselect row in TableViewer but in case of second click to this row (means if i click on row which was previously selected) ?

By default 1st click marks this row ! , but I want that second click to this marked row will automaticaly deselect this row.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + Click will deselect the row,

Is this what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately your hint is not working. But anyway I ment if you click out of items in tableView, that selected will deselect.